# Get an object from the database after a put it there

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I save the model object in the database

```
 var orderModel = new Order
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            LastName = lastName,
            FirstName = firstName,
            MiddleName = middleName,
            Country = country,
            ZipCode = zipcode,
            City = city,
            Street = street,
            HomeLocation = homeLocation,
            Email = email,
            Phone = phone,
            Comment = comment,
            ItemId = orderedItem.Id,
            UserId = _dataManager.Users.GetUserById(new Guid("20ed0117-8747-44c5-b24b-95412661f403")).Id,
            CompanyId = _dataManager.Companys.GetCompanyById(ConfigurationInformation.GetCompanyId()).Id,
            CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Price = price,
            Quantity = quantity
        };
        _dataManager.Orders.SaveOrder(orderModel); // Save order
```

Then get this object:

```
 var order = _dataManager.Orders.GetOrderById(orderModel.Id);
```

User, Company and Item are null

My model looks like this:

```
 public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string HomeLocation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public System.DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

If I get this object using the new data context, then everything will be fine:

```
var order = (new BussinesLogic.DataDirections.QuillingShopDataContext()).Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == orderModel.Id)
```

How do I get this to not using a new data context?

Comment: Nice of you to share your data model with your views so I can just change the price of my order by dropping a "price" field into the form before I submit it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! How can we realize that it was impossible to change the price before the order fulfillment?

Comment: You need to separate your domain model and your view model by creating *separate* classes for your view models and then mapping the relevant data (i.e. don't map the price from the view model). If you expose your domain model to your views, your users can modify *any* property by making the right post request.

Answer (score 0):

I found in EF5 the in memory copy was not updated after a save to store, I ended up using .Local

as explained here [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592872.aspx)